# Failed to execute script pyi_rth_tkinter

Tags: python

I'm trying to download lots of exe files which act as image pop-ups. So when they are downloaded I simply just run them. But I get this error does anyone know why.

Here's the code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z2hB.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSS5M.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOUut.png

sorry for the stupidly long code.

and also here's the error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeQ30.png

Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome @Jefrey,
please try to use inline Code as this  [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) shows

Comment: What a wonderful error message!

Comment: Thanks for the responses and yes I fixed it thanks, guys.